# Returning of string pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers

I have a program with function which I supposed to provide the string as and argument and return the part of a string . Such that I want to return a pointer to the calling function as

```
int test_func(char *dest, const char *src)
  {
    int i,n,len_in_msg,j;
    char *rem_string;

    n=strlen(src);
    for (i = 0; i < n && src[i] != '\n'; i++)
      {
        dest = src+i;
      }
    printf("value of i  = %d ",i);

    dest = dest+2;
    printf("dest = %s", dest);
    return 1;
  }
```

Here I have a string as `"100000\nis  hhhhhhhh";` I want to separate `"100000"` and next string such that I want to return the later part as a pointer in `dest` to the calling function.

The `dest` is printed fine in the `test_func()` however it is not reflected in the calling function.

Even I tried calling as

```
int main()
{
    int msg_pointer = -1;
    int msg_length;
    char *test;
    char *test1;
    char *msg_full = "100000\nis  hhhhhhhh";
    //test = malloc(sizeof(char)*(100));

    msg_length = test_func(test, msg_full);

    printf("value of test = %s", test);
}
```

Also as `&test` but no luck.  How can I achieve this??

Answer (score 3):

```
char *test;
/* ... */
msg_length = test_func(test,msg_full);
```

You are passing `test` an uninitialized pointer to `test_func`. If you want to modify a pointer object passed in parameter, use a pointer to a pointer:

```
int test_func(char **dest, const char *src)
{
   /* change the body accordingly to new dest type */
}
```

and:

```
 msg_length = test_func(&test,msg_full);
```

Comment: Also inside test_func, change  dest = src+i; to *dest = src+i;

Comment: I have tried it but it returns null in the calling function

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing the *address of* `test` to `test_func`, within `test_func`, you must treat `*dest` as your pointer, not `dest`. For example, after passing `&test` through the parameter `char **dest`, you must allocate space for the *value* of `dest` not `dest` itself:

```
*dest = malloc (sizeof **dest * (len + 1));
```

That is what ouah meant when he stated:

> ```
> /* change the body accordingly to new dest type */
> ```

I think your code should work following that change. If you run into additional issues, here is a slightly different variant on your approach that you can draw from:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int test_func (char **dest, char *src, char delim);

int main (void)
{
    int msg_length = 0; 
    char *test = NULL;
    char *msg_full = "100000\nis  hhhhhhhh";

    msg_length = test_func (&test, msg_full, '\n');

    printf ("\n value of test = '%s' (%d chars)\n\n", test, msg_length);

    if (test) free (test);  /* free allocated memory */

    return 0;
}

/* copy characters in 's' following 'delim' to
   newly allocated block of memory in 'str' */
int test_func (char **dest, char *src, char delim)
{
    size_t len = 0;
    char *p = src;
    char *new = NULL;

    /* set p at start of second string, save pointer
       to start of second in new */
    while (*p) if (*p++ == delim) break;
    new = p;

    while (*p++) len++; /* length of new */

    *dest = malloc (sizeof **dest * (len + 1)); /* allocate */

    p = new;        /* set p to new    */
    new = *dest;    /* set new to dest */
    while (*p) { *new = *p++; new++; }  /* copy to *dest */

    return (int)len;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/splitintwo

 value of test = 'is  hhhhhhhh' (12 chars)
```

One last *note:* (maybe 2), pay closer attention to your data types. (it matters). I have left the function return types as `int` as well as `msg_length` in your code, but they should really be `unsigned int` (or more properly `size_t`). Why? *You cannot have a negative length.* Get in the habit of matching your `type` to the information you are handling. This will become increasingly more important the further you progress in C.

`main` is a special function, with a required declaration. It is type `'int'`, meaning it must return a value (even if MS let's you get away without it). It should be declared with the required parameters `(int argc, char **argv)`, even though for short snippets I don't always do that (evidenced by the code above). If you are not going to give the full declaration, at least explicitly tell the compiler what you are doing (e.g. `int main (void)`). While not *technically* correct, it is much cleaner than simply providing empty parens.